# Can someone explain how to rework this from two observableArrays into one?

Tags: knockout.js, observable

http://jsfiddle.net/Gm64C/2/

The data used is inline at the top of the javascript panel.

If you click on the "show details" link in the result panel, you'll get some more data associated with that drug populated below the list in a table.  If you click on "edit" in the drugName row, you can change that drug name.  If you change the name, it will be reflected in the data table and the header above the data table.  It will **not** be updated in the list at the top of the results panel (that is a different observableArray).

I can't figure out how to make this all work with one observableArray.  I'm populating my **drugList** oservableArray with **data.preferredDrugs** (this is an array of objects I then iterate over using foreach: drugList).  If I populate that with just data, I'm not sure how to iterate over just the preferredDrugs array of objects.  This is why I ended up with two observableArrays - one for the drug names, the other for the drug details.

How can I make this work using one observableArray so if you edit a drug name in the table, it's reflected **everywhere**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked your fiddle to remove the dependency on jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/EPFbQ/

Some things to point out on the fixes:

- Since you want to be able to edit the name and have the changes be visible, you need to make at least the name observable.

  ```js
  self.drugList = ko.observableArray(
      ko.utils.arrayMap(data.preferredDrugs, function (obj) {
          return ko.utils.extend(obj, {
              "drugName": ko.observable(obj["drugName"]),
          });
      })
  );
  ```
- It would be easier if you keep track of the selected drug, the contents of the editing text box and the state of whether or not you are editing.  This will help simplify your view and view model code.  Knockout will work out all the rest.

  ```js
  // current drug
  self.currentDrug = ko.observable();

  // flag indicating we're editing the currently selected drug name
  self.isEditing   = ko.observable(false);
  // observable representing the editing text box
  self.editTextBox = ko.observable();
  // this will help with setting focus on the text box
  self.editTextBox.hasfocus= ko.observable(false);
  ```
- Saving edits is now just a matter of setting the selected object's name to the contents of the edit text box.

  ```
  // save an edit
  self.editSave = function (obj) {
      // copy the edited name to the current drug name
      obj.drugName(self.editTextBox());

      self.isEditing(false);
  };
  ```
- You can use the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) to set the context of your bindings instead of `foreach` as you had.
- Use the bindings to set the css classes and toggling visibility, knockout will do the grunt work for you.

  ```html
  <td data-bind="css: { 'editing': $root.isEditing }">
      <span data-bind="visible: !$root.isEditing(), text: drugName" class="readonly"></span>
      <input id="edit_drugname" data-bind="value: $root.editTextBox, hasfocus: $root.editTextBox.hasfocus, css: { 'edit_textfield': !$root.isEditing() }" type="text" value="" size="35" />
      <button data-bind="click: $root.editSave, css: { 'edit_buttons': !$root.isEditing() }" class="save">Save</button>
      <button data-bind="click: $root.editCancel, css: { 'edit_buttons': !$root.isEditing() }" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
      <ul class="detail_actions" data-bind="visible: !$root.isEditing()">
          <li><a data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" class="edit">edit</a></li>
      </ul>
  </td>
  ```

Comment: Hmm, the focusing part isn't as bulletproof as I had hoped.  It only works the first time.

Comment: What about using the mapping plugin so I don't have duplication of data in my arrays?  That's what I'm looking at now.  I can get it working with static data, but seem to be having issues with loading in data from the server.

Comment: Sure you can use the mapping plugin.  If you want to be able to edit all fields, then it will definitely help.  Otherwise if you only want to be able to edit the name and maybe a few other fields, then you won't necessarily need it and can just map out the required fields like I've shown for `drugName`. Just remember to do this mapping with the data you get back from your server.